# How can I restore parcelable list in android

Tags: android, parcel

I have this app that in an activity creates a list of players and displays them in a listview. When I create a player I use the populatePlayerList method and it works fine. But when I save the list in a parcel and try to restore it, it doesn't populate the listview. Can't figure out why this happens. Below is some code:

```
public class PlayerManager extends AppCompatActivity {

            EditText playerName, playerNumber, playerPosition;
            ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
            ListView playerListView;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_manager);

                playerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayerName);
                playerNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayerNumber);
                playerPosition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPlayerPosition);
                playerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.playerList);

                if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                    players = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("savedList");
                    populatePlayerList();
                }

                final Button addPlayerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddPlayer);

                addPlayerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        addPlayer(playerName.getText().toString(), playerNumber.getText().toString(), playerPosition.getText().toString());
                        populatePlayerList();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerName.getText().toString() + " added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });          

            private void populatePlayerList(){
                ArrayAdapter<Player> adapter = new PlayerListAdapter();
                playerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            private void addPlayer(String name, String number, String position){
                players.add(new Player(name, number, position));
        }

        private class PlayerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
                public PlayerListAdapter(){
                    super(PlayerManager.this, R.layout.player_list, players);
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
                    if (view == null)
                        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player_list, parent, false);

                    Player currentPlayer = players.get(position);

                    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerName);
                    name.setText(currentPlayer.get_name());
                    TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerNumber);
                    number.setText(currentPlayer.get_number());
                    TextView playerPosition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.playerPosition);
                    playerPosition.setText(currentPlayer.get_position());

                    return view;
                }
            }

    @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putParcelableArrayList("savedList", players);
        }
```

Here is my Player Class:

```
public class Player implements Parcelable{

    private String name, position,number;

    public Player (String name, String number, String position) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.position = position;
    }

    protected Player(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        position = in.readString();
        number = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Player>() {
        @Override
        public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Player(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Player[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Player[size];
        }
    };


    public String get_name() {
        return name;
    }

    public String get_position() {
        return position;
    }

    public String get_number(){
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(position);
        dest.writeString(number);
    }
}
```

I checked the players list when i try to restore it and its empty. So i guess its never saved in outState. Any ideas why?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you check the list has the players, once you are trying to restore it?

Comment: yeap, when I create players I can see them in the listview, but when i go to another activity and the return to this the list is gone

Comment: I mean, the code enter here: if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                    players = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("savedList");
                    populatePlayerList();
                } ?

Comment: You are right leo! the list is fine at first but its empty when I try to restore it. So I guess there's something wrong with outState.putParcelableArrayList("savedList", players); but I can't understand what. My Player class extends Parcelable.

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Did you set a breakpoint on if(savedInstanceState != null) to make sure it is actually going into that case when you think it is?  If savedInstanceState is null it means that you are using a new PlayerManager  instead of an automatically saved one.   Side Note: A good habit to get into would be to define "savedList" as a static final string and use it in both places - that way you'll never have an issue where the strings don't match.

Comment: Yes I did, and it never goes in the case if(savedInstanceState != null). It goes on else case meaning savedInstanceState is null and the list is never saved on the parcel. and I cant figure why this is happening

Comment: State is only restored after a configuration change (like changing screen orientation) or after the Activity has been unloaded to free memory while the app was not visible, then loaded back when the user navigates back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by adding android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the PlayerManager activity in Android Manifest.xml file. And I override the onBackPressed to sent me back to a previous activity so the onDestroy method isn't called. That way I get to keep the same instance in the PlayerManager activity.